# secure shell "selection copied"

Tags: ssh, chrome, clipboard

I'm using `ASUS Chromebook Flip` with `Google Chrome OS` (`58.0.3029.18 dev (32-bit)`) and [Secure Shell (from Chrome Web Store)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo?hl=en).

I'm *trying* to perform `Copy` and`Paste` from `Secure Shell` tab, by selecting text, I even get following message:

> Selection copied

however, I cannot `Paste` selected text anywhere( not even inside of the same tab or anywhere really(

---

> By default, Secure Shell automatically copies your active selection to
>   the clipboard.

- [How do I copy text from the terminal?](https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/master/nassh/doc/FAQ.md#How-do-I-copy-text-from-the-terminal)
- [How do I paste text to the terminal?](https://chromium.googlesource.com/apps/libapps/+/master/nassh/doc/FAQ.md#How-do-I-paste-text-to-the-terminal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a known issue w/canary: [695568 - cannot copy text from hterm to clipboard - chromium - Monorail](https://crbug.com/695568)

you can workaround it by going into your options and turning use-default-window-copy on.

[Copy-paste broken with Chrome OS update - Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-hterm/34chnTnO-hg)

Comment: Link-only answers are not allowed. Please explained summary of procedure in external site in answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot fo the answer, I had this annoying issue on my machine too.

Comment: the links aren't the answer, they're references to the upstream project.  explaining how Chrome+hterm are broken together here isn't terribly useful.  the actual workaround is here for people to read directly.